# Kicks out of bounds

Tags: american-football

I have some situations

1. Kickoff touched by receiving team goes out of bounds, who gets the ball? I mean the RT doesn't fumble but only muffed the kickoff.
2. Kickoff muffed by RT (or after 10 yards) then touched by KT and finally it goes out of bounds? Who gets the ball?
3. Muffed punt by RT goes out of bounds, who gets the ball
4. Muffed punt by RT then touched by KT and finally it goes out of bounds, who gest the ball?

Answer (score 2):

For all of these questions, unless the kicking team legally gains possession of the ball in the field of play, the receiving team will have the ball.   That doesn't happen in your scenarios, so the receiving team will have the ball for the next play in all four cases.

Touching the ball may give the other team certain rights in some situations, but it does not change possession.

From [2023 NFL Rules](https://operations.nfl.com/media/tvglh0mx/2023-rulebook_final.pdf)

1. 6/2/3 Ball placed at out-of-bounds location.
2. 6/2/3 25 yards from kick or at out-of-bounds location, RT choice.
3. and 4.  9/4/4 (assuming no illegal batting), out-of-bounds location.

Answer (score 1):

Any punt goes out of bounds is a ball is put back by RT where it goes out of bounds.
In all those cases:

1. Punt Untouched out bounds
2. Muffed punt by KT
3. Muffed punt by RT
4. Muffed punt by RT and then the ball hitted by KT out.

For kickoff we have the penality only if goes out of bounds untouched.
If the kickoff

1. Muffed by RT
2. Muffed by KT
3. Muffed by RT then it hitted by KT out.
   The play restarts in possession of RT at the spot where the ball goes out of play.
   Am I right?